# How do I specify a pip-installed, editable dependency in a conda environment YAML file?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, development-environment

I'm developing a python package in a conda environment defined by a YAML environment file. my question is: is there a way to specify this local package as an editable, pip-installed dependency in the YAML file?

my conda env YAML file looks something like as follows ([env files documented here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually)):

```
name: ...
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - <packages on conda-forge>
  - pip:
    - <packages on PyPI>
    - git+https://github.com/<some packages on github>
```

currently, i first create this env with `conda env create -n env.yml` and then manually install the package with `pip install --no-build-isolation --editable .`.

i'm wondering if it's possible to add an entry under   `- pip:` for my package in the environment file. i've searched the documentation and can't find anything on whether or how this is possible. any help appreciated!

Comment: just like pip (add a `-e` before the package)